# how to store online status

Tags: websockets, redis, online-identity

I'm developing realtime web chat using [pubsub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) pattern. To be concrete I'm using python and tornado-redis on back end and websockets (WS) (tornado) on front end. I have WS connection open and close events. So I stuck with the problem what is the best solution to store current online user list.

**Here are some theses**:

- I would like to run multiple threads so data about online users should
  persists in accessible for all place. [Horizontal scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11715598/3872976) requires the same.
- One user can open multiple connections. Meaning same username can be present in multiple connection instances.

**Solutions**:

- Store in nowhere! Meaning when I need current online just broadcast message to all and determine who's online from responses. **(+)** I know **real** userlist everytime, **(-)** this is increasing processing time and complicating implementation).
- Store current online in database in a separate table. Every table row matches a single connection. (In current realization it's redis hmap. `{"hash of current connection" : "username"}`. [hset](http://redis.io/commands/hset) on WS opening *(a user connects)*, [hdel](http://redis.io/commands/hdel) on WS closing *(user disconnects)*. **(+)** Fast if I just need to get current online, **(-)** If a user disconnects and database connection is lost the same time the DB info would be wrong.
- Specific to redis and my current realization. Since I have a single redis connection per WS connection I can store user info in tornado [clientname](http://redis.io/commands/client-setname). Since redis already has info about connected users. I can get [client-list](http://redis.io/commands/client-list), filter it by some criteria (clientname) and get online. **(+)** I delegate online to redis . **(-)** Storing multiple online lists becomes complicated. For example if webchat has multiple rooms  (lets assume 100) storing online for a every room in a single place looks a bit messy.

Which solution best meets my requirements, or do you have a better solution?

Comment: Resource recommendations are off-topic, and open-ended questions may be closed as "too broad." I think the core of your question is fine, so I edited that language out. Please keep that in mind when asking future questions.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question on random, but here's how I would do it:

On your `users` table, create a column called `lastActivity` and make it a `DateTime` type.

When connecting via the websocket, have the client authenticate the socket connection, (like sending an `authToken` or however you like). When authenticating, you set the id of the `user` as a property on the connection.

After authenticating, have the client send periodic messages to the server.

When the server receives the message, update the `lastActivity` on the user, use the id you set on the connection to find the user that is sending the message.

Now in your application you can simply compare the `lastActivity` field, for example if it is older than 10 seconds and you have it set to send a message every 10 seconds, the user could be considered offline.